# If this condition is true, are these functions equal?

Tags: solution-verification, affine-geometry

Take two affine maps $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and consider $\Omega=\{p \in \mathbb{R^n}:f(p)=g(p)\}$. If the interior of $\Omega$ is not empty, is it true that $f=g$?

I reason as follows: the set $\Omega$ is the kernel of the affine map $f-g$ and therefore it is an affine subspace. As the only affine subspace with non-empty interior is the total, $\Omega=\mathbb{R^n}$ and therefore $f=g$. Is it correct?

Comment: q(p)? I think you meant f(p)=g(p)...

Comment: @giorgiokyn23 yes, sorry

Comment: By translation, you can assume that on a ball centred at the origin, $f(p) = g(p);$ but then, $f = g$ for some basis.

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.